# Compare zip file and extracted directory

Tags: files, macos, zip, compression, checksum

What is the simplest way to compare a zip file and a directory that has been extracted from the zip file? I would like to delete the zip file if they are the same.

**Example.** Need to check if `Archive.zip` and `travel_photos/` directory contain the same files (i.e., if all files inside `Archive.zip` have been correctly extracted to `travel_photos/`).

**Limitation.** I cannot change how the archive creation and the extraction was done. These files are given to me and I need to check them afterwards. This means, I cannot create a file with the checksums of all files inside `Archive.zip`.

**Requirement.** I do not want to create another zip archive from `travel_photos/` because I need to work with large directories and may not have enough space to write additional big files. For this reason, points 2-5 below are not good, although I tried them to see what might work.

**What I've tried so far.**

1. compare `md5sum Archive.zip` and `(cd travel_photos; zip -rqq - *) | md5sum`,
2. compare `(cd travel_photos; zip -rqq ../test.zip *); md5sum test.zip` and `md5sum Archive.zip`,
3. compare `unzip -p test.zip | md5sum` and `unzip -p Archive.zip | md5sum`
4. `zcmp test.zip Archive.zip` (also with `zdiff`)
5. `unzip -vql test.zip | sort -k8 | md5sum` and `unzip -vql Archive.zip | sort -k8 | md5sum`

**Partial solution.** If I change the last example above to remove the fields `Cmpr` and `Size` (somehow the file sizes are different in the two archives even though the files are exactly the same?) and remove the total archive size from the first two lines, then I can verify that the archives are the same.

```bsh
diff -W200 -y <(unzip -vql test.zip | sort -k8 | awk '{if(NR>2) print ($1"\t"$2"\t"$5"\t"$6"\t"$7"\t"$8)}' ) <(unzip -vql Archive.zip | sort -k8 | awk '{if(NR>2) print ($1"\t"$2"\t"$5"\t"$6"\t"$7"\t"$8)}' ) --suppress-common-lines
```

The drawback of this solution is that I need to create and save `test.zip` to disk. Is there a way to do this comparison but between the directory `travel_photos/` and the zipfile `Archive.zip`? I tried to pipe the output of zip command as below but it didn't work.

```bsh
diff -W200 -y <(unzip -vql Archive.zip | sort -k8 | awk '{if(NR>2) print ($1"\t"$2"\t"$5"\t"$6"\t"$7"\t"$8)}' ) < ((cd travel_photos; zip -rqq - *) > unzip -vql | sort -k8 | awk '{if(NR>2) print ($1"\t"$2"\t"$5"\t"$6"\t"$7"\t"$8)}' ) --suppress-common-lines
```

Comment: Welcome, there a spaces in the file names? And there are subdirectories?

Comment: No spaces in file names and no subdirectories.

Comment: @schrodigerscatcuriosity I think I saw an answer yesterday but it seems to have disappeared?

Answer (score 0):

You can use "folderdiff" (https://pypi.org/project/folderdiff/) to compare the contents of a folder with the contents of a ZIP archive, without storing the files to disk.

It's also possible to compare the contents of 2 ZIP archives.

"folderdiff" was created to compare a webapplication (e.g. wordpress) with a trusted source and find modified or added files which can contain backdoors.

For each file a SHA256 hash is calculated and compared with the trusted source. "folderdiff" requires 2 arguments. The first one is the trusted source and the second one is the folder, which should be compared to the trusted source.

Following example shows how to find backdoors in an existing wordpress installation:

```
$ folderdiff wordpress-6.0.3-de_AT.zip /var/www/ --prefix wordpress/
===================== Added ======================
+ webshell.php
==================== Modified ====================
* index.php
```

Disclosure: I'm the author of folderdiff